# Ink.Runtime not found

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to use Ink for my Unity Project.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/ink-unity-integration-60055

After installation through the Package Manager, everything on Unity seems to work fine (Ink files can be created, they get compiled to JSON, the Ink Player tab works, etc etc) - with one exception:

[image]

I can't get VisualStudio to find the `Ink` namespace. I've tried restarting it and Unity. It worked fine for other packages like the new Unity Input system and TextMeshPro.

What can I do to fix this?

Edit: Regenerating project files with all checkboxes checked doesn't seem to work either.

Edit 2: If I open a C# script from Ink itself (Asset/Ink/*), then VS seems to recognize Ink.Runtime. Its only in my own scripts (which are also in Asset/*) that don't have the namespace:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I managed to fix it by deleting the ".vs" folder inside the project folder.